# Is there a way to prevent Windows from caching network files?

Tags: c#, windows, caching, file-io, network-drive

I have a piece of commercial software that is writing out customer information to a binary file on a networked Windows drive. The architecture prevents me from using anything other than this networked drive.

I have a C# application that I've written to parse data from this binary file. This application simply sits in a loop, waiting for that file to be modified, then it parses the customer information looking for what changed. It will then update the customer's record in my own custom database.

The problem:

- I use the commercial package to update a customer record (I can even hex dump the file and see the modification)
- My C# application reads this same file (presumably), but it's not seeing the customer updates. What it is reading is identical to the previous parse

I'm a Linux guy and my first thought was that I've seen similar issues on Linux NFS mounts, and fixed them although it's been so long ago I don't remember the exact solution.

I've tried:

- Using the group policy editor to disable offline files for all files. This didn't work.
- Generic long sleeps before reading the updated binary files after a customer has been changed. This didn't work.
  ** Interesting note here is that my code will detect the modified time stamp and process it, but the contents seem to be cached still
- I've triple checked all my internal data structures to ensure they're clean on each iteration. No buffered data there.
- Even found one hack online where a guy said if you add a file to that same directory, then delete it, it somehow forces a directory refresh. This did not work but highlighted the problem in a different way. If I create the temp/hack  file then immediately try to delete it, it doesn't work because my application doesn't see the new hack file. Even with a couple second sleep thrown between the creation and deletion.
- I've tried, programatically, to move this file to the same file name with an _ on the end before reading it. My thought was that writing this new file, which would always be unique, would somehow force Windows to give me the latest and greatest from that folder. When I try to read this new/unique file, though, it tells me the file isn't found even though I can see it through Windows Explorer. Seems like I'm reading in some cached version of that directory.

Odd test behavior:

- If I stop my application and restart it, it always reads the newest copy of the file. That's what led me first to rechecking all my internal data structures to see if I wasn't clearing a buffer or something. But that's not the case.

Operationally, there are multiple users and sites that are modifying this customer data so it's a lot of data changing very rapidly. I simply need a way to force a read of the actual data file. Thanks for any help any of you can provide.

UPDATE:
Using some of the comments, I got it to work, but I wouldn't say I actually found a solution. It's just a hack. I just combined everything I thought should work before (but didn't) and gave it a test. First, I copy the file to the same directory with seconds since epoch tacked onto the end. Then, I go into a loop looking for that file by checking FileInfo.Exists. When it doesn't see it, I FileInfo.Refresh(), sleep a second, and try again. It's taken up to 15 seconds to break out of this loop in my bit of testing. After a minute of this, it'll error out just to prevent an endless loop here. Then I delete the temporary file.

Again, I know this is incredibly ugly and kludgy so I'm still interested in anyone with answers on how to handle this more properly.

Comment: Are you holding a `FileStream` open to the file or are you re-opening the file when you detect changes in the `FileInfo` properties?

Comment: Where is located this network drive? Is it on some DFS share?

Comment: _"When the properties are first retrieved, FileInfo calls the Refresh method and caches information about the file. **On subsequent calls, you must call Refresh to get the latest copy of the information**."_ - From [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2). May this be the problem? I gues you'll be fine if you hit Refresh on the FileInfo before creating the FileStream (given you are using both - Do you?).

Comment: @Corey I'm opening the file, reading it into a buffer, and closing it before doing any more processing.

Comment: @montonero It's another windows host with a big shared area. Just mapped network drives.

Comment: @Fildor thanks. I'll try that in the morning and report.

Comment: If the hex editor sees the changes then your app should see them as well, right? Caching is not per-app but per instance of the OS.; I admit that I don't know how SMB caching works but I doubt that it allows the kind of inconsistency you are talking about. That would break a lot of apps and scenarios (such as editing a Word file on an SMB share). This can't be.

Comment: `If I stop my application and restart it, it always reads the newest copy of the file.` this together with my previous comment makes me think that it's a bug in your code 99.999% chance.

Comment: @usr No, it's not a bug in the app. And laggy share updates are an incredibly common thing. I've run into things like this in the past with NFS on Linux machines, but that's just a simple config item. Windows ... not so much. As I mentioned in my update, it seems like it's taking around 15 seconds to finally synch up with the file. It was apparently taking me longer than that to fire up VI and switch it to hex mode to look at the file so I was always seeing the newest one, but AFTER the original application had already blown through the old/cached one.

Comment: What I need, essentially, is a Windows file share equivalent of shutting off the lookup cache in NFS.

Comment: OK, that's evidence for your view. But what about "Caching is not per-app but per instance of the OS."? All apps on the same OS instance should see the same view. On Windows, there is zero caching per-process. Maybe you can further test the theory by writing a 10 line program that in a loop reads the file, compares the bytes with the previous read and outputs any change to the console. Make it read 10 times per second and post the code here.